# PDF compression on Unix command line

Tags: shell, pdf, ghostscript

I have a PDF file which has a header image, a footer image and text between both. The file size is approximately 250-280 KB depending on the text between it.

I have tried this Ghostscript command:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.1 \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=false -dSubsetFonts=false \
   -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=32 \
   -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=32 \
   -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=32 \
   -r \
   -sOutputFile=$2 \
    $1
```

I can achieved compressing a 250 KB file to 68 KB, but the image here is distorted.

I need file size near to 20 KB. Black & white PDF will also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what you mean by 'distorted'. Certainly almost any image is going to look pretty poor after you downsample it so severely!

There is no way using Ghostscript to get a 'black and white' result. You can use the ColorConversionStrategy to get a Gray output, but that's all.

I really wouldn't use -dPDFSETTINGS as that sets a lot of switches, many of which may be inappropriate for your needs. Instead set the switches you want individually.

I also wouldn't set the CompatibilityLevel so low, that's simply likely to lead to more of the content being rendered to images, which is likely to **increase** the size of your PDF file.

Comment: by distorted I mean nothing is visible on the image it gets super blurred. I will try out the gray scale and the compatibility level settings and reply back Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I got it to compress down to 45 KB and I think it cannot go below that.